# ¿Cómo hacer que el floatingactionbutton se muestre completo?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Tengo un floating action button que agregué a un fragment y el botón aparece, pero se muestra a medias y cuando hago scroll se muestra completo... ¿Cómo hacer que el botón se muestre completo y que al hacer scroll siga allí? Dejo el código y un screenshot para mostrar cómo me aparece el botón

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 FloatingActionButton mas=(FloatingActionButton)v.findViewById(R.id.mas);
        mas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), formadopcion.class);
                adoptions.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

el código del xml

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
    />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/mas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

@Elenasys Te adjunto la imagen completa del screenshot para que puedas observar cómo me aparece a mi, hasta que hago scroll es cuando lo veo completo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para determinar donde puede estar el problema muestra todo el layout.xml

Comment: @Leudiz agrega todo el layout.

Comment: @Elenasys y Webserveis he editado la pregunta para añadir todo el layout, gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: Prueba a poner tanto el `CoordinatorLayout` como el `RecyclerView` con `height` a `wrap_content`.

Comment: @Error404 Ya subió el botón ahora si, sólo que a la mitad pero ya me doy una idea de cómo acomodarlo... muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: @LeyDizz Deberías de agregar la solución como respuesta y borrar la respuesta que tienes actualmente. Si no has resuelto todavía tu duda, siempre puedes editar tu pregunta con el nuevo código y a poder ser una imagen para poder ver cual es el problema actual. Gracias! :)

Comment: Entiendo, aún no tengo la solución, sólo se recorrió el botón, aún seguimos trabajando en eso. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del RecyclerView cambia a `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
/>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/mas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/plus"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Sigue con el mismo problema aún así quitando el Linearlayout  y cambiando lo demás que me recomendaste. Estoy trabajando con tabs y en la pestaña de "adopciones" es donde puse el botón, no se si tenga algo que ver el que se muestre de esa manera el botón ya que lo tenía de prueba en otro activity y hacía que el floatinactionbutton apareciera en todas las pestañas sin embargo aparecía en su lugar y ahora no.

Comment: modifiqué el layout @LeyDizz

Comment: El problema persiste, le haga la modificación que le haga sigue donde mismo, debe ser algún problema que necesito checar bien con los layout o algo así. Gracias por tu ayuda, de antemano.

Comment: Acabo de probar tu layout y se muestra el botón perfectamente en lado derecho abajo, en verdad aparece cortado el botón ?